# MSSQL table copy data to MYSQL table

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, php-5.3

I've been searching for a while. And I also developed from scratch a php script to copy all data from a MSSQL to MYSQL. I've went with a staggered approach to avoid load and keep footprint minimal. Timeouts are also not an issue as I'm setting php timeouts to 0 (infinite)

Now the data in my MSSQL table have around 500000 rows and the copying over is failing. I'm connecting to mssql via php and also to mysql via php, using php's built in functions.

The error I'm receiving is not helpful at all. Error is saying "Error in mssql_query"

Is there any efficient way to do this from your experience?

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to account for special characters such as records with a single quote(') ? (ie Michael's hotdogs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a lot of tools to migrate from mssql to mysql, try them instead of writing your own code. one them is :

http://opendbcopy.sourceforge.net/